# OpenAM - Is there a way to disable new organisation message while switching between realms?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam, ws-federation, opensso

In our OpenAM implementation, we have two realms with different relying parties configured in it. Both the realms authenticate against the same LDAP source. 
We adopted this configuration to avoid certain edge cases.

Now, whenever we switch between the relying parties in these realms, the new organisation warning message keeps showing up:

> "You have already logged in. Do you want to log out and then login to
>   a different organisation?"

Is there a way to seamlessly allow users to access the different realms using the same authenticated session ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. A session is associated with one realm, so a user a can not be authenticated to two realms at the same time.

Perhaps a better strategy is to examine why two different realms are required. It sounds like the two RPs should really be in the same realm if they serve the same group of users.